# Bibliography error: illegal unit of measure

Tags: bibliographies

I am preparing a submission to a journal using [their template (QIC LaTeX2e)](https://www.rintonpress.com/style/). I am compiling in a default Overleaf project and have added a number of packages in order to use my macros: `\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, nicefrac, hyperref, amssymb, listings, xcolor}`. When presented with the sample bibliography

```
\begin{thebibliography}{000}
\bibitem{first}
P. Horodecki and R. Horodecki (2001), {\it Distillation and bound entanglement},
Quantum Inf. Comput., Vol.1, pp. 045-075.

\bibitem{cal}
R. Calderbank and P. Shor (1996), {\it Good quantum error
       correcting codes exist},
Phys. Rev. A, 54, pp. 1098-1106.

\bibitem{niel}
M.A. Nielsen and J. Kempe (2001), {\it Separable states are
more disordered globally than locally}, quant-ph/0105090.

\bibitem{mar}
A.W. Marshall and I. Olkin (1979), {\it Inequalities: theory of majorization and its applications},
Academic Press (New York).
\end{thebibliography}
```

the citations are presented in the output preceded by "pt!" and Overleaf gives the following errors:

```
Package calc Error: `0' invalid at this point.

See the calc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.230 \bibitem
              {first}
I expected to see one of: + - * / )

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.230 \bibitem
              {first}
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'. (If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number, look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)
```

```
Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).

<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.230 \bibitem
              {first}
Dimensions can be in units of em, ex, in, pt, pc, cm, mm, dd, cc, nd, nc, bp, or sp; but yours is a new one! I'll assume that you meant to say pt, for printer's points. To recover gracefully from this error, it's best to delete the erroneous units; e.g., type `2' to delete two letters. (See Chapter 27 of The TeXbook.)
```

```
LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

There are no entries found in a list you have created. Make sure you label list entries using the \item command, and that you have not used a list inside a table.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.230 \bibitem
              {first}
Try typing  <return>  to proceed. If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.
```

It seems that the compiler does not like the names given to the `bibitem`s, and for some reason expects a length.

Here is the code from the style file for `thebibliography`:

```
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
        {\frenchspacing
         \small\rm\baselineskip=11pt
         \begin{list}{\arabic{enumi}.}
        {\usecounter{enumi}\setlength{\parsep}{0pt}     
%         \setlength{\leftmargin 12.7pt}{\rightmargin 0pt}%FOR 1--9 ITEMS
          \setlength{\leftmargin 17pt}{\rightmargin 0pt}  %FOR 10--99 ITEMS
%         \setlength{\leftmargin 22pt}{\rightmargin 0pt}   %FOR 100+ABOVE ITEMS
         \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt} \settowidth
          {\labelwidth}{#1.}\sloppy}}{\end{list}}
```

What is the cleanest solution to resolve these errors? I'd really prefer not to have to ditch my macros and the corresponding prerequisite packages.

Comment: If you are submitting to a journal, unless the journal has okay-ed it, you shouldn't use your own custom macros and should only use the ones that they have given in you in the `qic.sty` file. Do they mention if using custom macros is okay or not somewhere, typically journals want you to use only their template and not add other stuff as they do stuff with it afterwards as it passes through the publication process

Comment: I generally agree, however I've published with this same journal in the past and that time submitted an entire extra `.sty` file and there were no problems (either with compilation on my end or that they expressed to me in the galley process).

Comment: `\setlength{\leftmargin 12.7pt}{\rightmargin 0pt}` is nonsense. that should be `\setlength{\leftmargin}{12.7pt}\setlength{\rightmargin}{0pt}`.
For some reason the faulty syntax doesn't error with normal LaTeX but explodes only if the calc package is used.

Comment: @zjs that's perfect then, just didn't want you wasting your time debugging something that was got rid off in the end! Hope someone can answer :)